# Exporting R regression results to tables for publication

Tags: r, export, export-to-excel, regression, stata

I'm wondering if R has a function to store multiple regression results, decide what you want to keep from them (e.g. not interested in confidence intervals) and then export these results into a convenient table in Word or a .rtf document that can be inserted into academic work.

I'm thinking about the functionality the `esttab` command in Stata allows.

So for instance in Stata you store the results after each executed regression using

```
est sto a1
```

Then once you've stored various versions, you can use the following command

```
esttab a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 using "C:\...\table_name.rtf", replace compress onecell nogaps stats(N N_g r2) star b(3) se(3) starlevels(* 0.05 ** 0.01 *** 0.001) title(Table 1: This is a Stata Table ) order(order of your variables in the produced table) keep(which variables to keep if there are some you don't want - useful for when you have time series year dummies for instance)
```

Anything similar?

Following a question by the responder (and minus 2 for the question???) an update using some of my code. It's very basic and the Stata code captures exactly what I want to do so I'm a bit confused about the negative scoring.

Imagine you have the following regressions:

```
    ctrl <- vv10 ~ ro_rnd + ro_int + ro_col + c_obj + ro_org2 + sc_org + sc_funding + sc_ties + sc_friends + sc_know + r_jobtime + r_wj + sen_match1 + search + lm.res + scenprop

lm.base <- lm(ctrl, data=d)
  temp1 <- summary(lm.base)

lm.main <- update(lm.base, ~. + r_netw_kn + r_brmean6 + r_conf3 + I(r_conf3^2) + r_wtwws, data=d) 
  temp2 <- summary(lm.main) # model 2

lm.intp1 <- update(lm.main, ~. + r_brmean6:r_conf3 + r_brmean6:I(r_conf3^2))
  temp3 <- summary(lm.intp1)
```

The summaries of three regressions are stored in three temporary lists called `temp1, temp2, and temp3`

From these three lists what I want is to be able to export specific sections (i.e. columns from the summary) so that I can keep the `estimate`, the `standard error`, and `the stars`, the model fit (in the case of lm regressions via `temp1[9]` and ideally re-order the variables, place the standard errors between brackets, and reduce the number of numbers after the comma, so that I can use them directly in a table for a paper. 
In Stata this is possible via the `esttab` command as mentioned before. Using `knitr` does not really allow me the flexibility to delete the things I don't need and create one table with multiple, stepwise, regressions in which new variables are added every step (which is the common approach to represent results in management).

Hope this clarification helps.

Comment: try this : library(knitr)

Comment: I guess there were two main problems with your original post: lack of R code and an assumption that Stata code would be self-evident or familiar to the R people you are addressing (unlikely in the great majority of cases). SO people often direct minor flak at, or more usually ignore, questions without sustained attempts to produce code yourself. Questions of the form "What is the code to do  this thing?" don't really fit the goals of the forum, although they are sometimes indulged.

Comment: In this case showing results from `esttab` might have been as or more informative than showing the syntax but showing that you tried R code is more important.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Don't know how to upload a Stata results table - also not sure whether this would be effective - but I hope I explained it better. I thought that by tagging both r and stata I would have been able to avoid the haters :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the question with some of your code? From there it can be determined how to extract.

As an example without seeing your model and R code, see how the questioner extracts results from the linear model `sec.reg` here: [XTS dates from different sources. Using R to calculate beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11802086/xts-dates-from-different-sources-using-r-to-calculate-beta)

The questioner extracts a specific piece of the model (alpha) to a table with the following code section contained in the loop:
`summary[n,1] <- coef(sec.reg)[1]`

Try package `xtable` for publication quality tables. You may also want to check out package `knitr` if you're not familiar.

Comment: Hi, that looks like a good step in the direction but I don't see how it extracts stars and standard errors.

Comment: Can you update the question with some of your code? From there it can be determined how to extract. In the linear model named sec.reg, the questioner extracts a specific piece of the model (alpha) to a table with the code section containing [n,1]. I'm on mobile, hence sloppy answer.

Comment: also see the stargazer package